# How to make the connection between Emacs, Cider, and shadow-cljs be less repetitive per project?

Tags: build, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, cider, shadow-cljs

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, re-frame, reagent, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

Usually, I build the project by executing the command `cider-jack-in-cljs` in Emacs, choosing `shadow-cljs`, then `shadow` for REPL type, and, finally, `app` for the building option.

Every time I execute `cider-jack-in-cljs`, I end up retyping the same things.

I would like to make this process more automatic. Also, I would like to avoid manual tweaks inside CIDER's package local files.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the root of the project, create a file called `/Users/pedro/projects/your-project/.dir-locals.el`

Make the content be:

```lisp
((nil . ((cider-preferred-build-tool . shadow-cljs)
         (cider-default-cljs-repl . shadow)
         (cider-shadow-default-options . ":app")
         (cider-shadow-watched-builds . (":app"))
         (cider-offer-to-open-cljs-app-in-browser . nil))))
```

Now, it is only necessary to execute `cider-jack-in-cljs` **for this specific project**.